# how to protect jsp pages from being open source

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I want to develop a commercial web application project. Is it possible to prevent users from downloading the jsp pages? Something like DLL files of ASP pages?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just take the compiled jsp .class files and put them under WEB-INF/classes by copying the top level of the jsp class' package (org).  Since they're servlets, you can declare them in your web.xml and map them to the url pattern where they would normally be found.

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>index_jsp</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.dirname.index_jsp</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>index_jsp</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/dirname/index.jsp</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you're going to do this, you'll want to translate and compile them as part of your build.  If you're using ant, check out the [jasper](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) task.